# c# Working out how many configurations of houses on land

Tags: c#

I have coding challenge I've set myself, but I'm a bit stuck and become a bit obsessed with it.

The challenge is finding how many houses of varying type would fit in a variable number of plots of land.

There will always be three types of house:

- Detached(1 plot)
- SemiDetached (2 plots)
- Terrace(3 plots)

Between each type of house(s), there must be an empty plot. Here are a couple of examples to illustrate the task

**Using a 5 plot grid:**

**3 Detached(3x1)**

[D][ ][D][ ][D]

**1 Detached(1x1), 1 SemiDetached(1x2)**

[ ][D][ ][S][S]

OR

[S][S][ ][D][ ]

OR

[D][ ][S][S][ ]

etc...

Programatically, I want to be able to pass in an array of house size numbers [1,1,1] or [2,1] for example, have a variable int called plotSize, which will hold how many plots there are, then create a mechanism to find how many variations of the values will fit into the plots, abiding by the one space rule.

My thinking so far is to convert the houseSize to binary in relation to the plot size, with 0 being spaces, 1's being house sizes, so if plotSize = 5,[1,1,1] would become [10101], [2,1] would become [11010], [01101], [01011] for example. I cant figure out how I would do this in c# though and would appreciate any advice or tips anyone could provide

Comment: without giving too much away: you are looking for Bit-operations on integers. one that you are particularly interested in is the Shift '>>'

Comment: I usually use a recursive algorithm to get combinations.  Each recursive level is a different index of the array.

Comment: @Benj Thank you so much, I had no idea you could do that and its been a great help. I've now managed to successfully convert my array of numbers to binary and bitshift them to provide variations. The only issue I think I have left is the bit shifted bits do not adhere to the "must have a space between groups" rule and cannot figure out how I would remedy that. For example (3,1) becomes 11101, and the left bit-shifted variations are 11011,10111,01111 and 11110. only 11101 and 10111 are valid with the rule. Is there anything further you could suggest? :)

Comment: @Nick sure, it's not that tough. you need two (bit-)masks or every house: one mask represents the squares each house will block and one mask represents the squares that the house needs to be empty (=spaces). after all the masks were created, you obtain a mask of all squares that need to be empty by OR-ing all `must be empty`-masks and then AND this mask with the logical OR of all masks that represent blocked squares by houses